# Complex MySql Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these tables:

- exams (medical exams)
- users
- institutions (medical institutions)
- users_institutions (join table)
- log (here i'm keeping date and time of Login, Logout, Downloads Files)

Users belongs to one or more institution, exams belong only to one institution. So, users can search into exam table only for exams that belong to their institution. The query that i use to get this is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM exams, institutions, users_institutions 
WHERE institutions.institution_pk = users_institutions.institution_fk
AND exams.institution_fk = institution.institution_pk
AND users.users_pk = {$user_id}
```

This code works fine. My problem is this:

**When a user download a PDF file from an exam I save date, time, user ID, exam ID, log type (1 for download, 2 for Login and 3 for Logout). I need a SQL Query to do a search of all exams that have not been downloaded yet and belong to their institutions for a particular user.
This means that if a have 10 users in a institution I need that every user have their own result set.**

Thanks!

(Sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pro tip: Never use `SELECT *` in software. Instead enumerate the columns you need in your result set. For one thing, it makes the server faster. For another thing, it makes it easier for the next person to understand your query's purpose.

Pro tip: Don't use the old-timey comma-separated table list for joins. Use joins.

Pro tip: Don't get hung up thinking this is complex. It's actually pretty straightforward.

Pro tip:  try to use the same column names for the same kind of value in each table. In other words call the user's id `user_id` in all the tables where it's mentioned. Don't call it `user_fk` or something else.

I think you want a query like this:

```
 SELECT u.users_pk, i.institution_pk, exams.id, whatever, whatever
   FROM users             AS u
   JOIN user_institutions AS ui ON u.users_pk = ui.user_fk
   JOIN institutions      AS i  ON us.institution_fk = i.institution_pk
   JOIN exams             AS e  ON e.institution_fk = i.institution_pk
   LEFT JOIN log          AS l  ON u.users_pk = l.users_fk 
                               AND e.exam_pk = l.exam_pk
                               AND l.logtype = 1
  WHERE l.exam_pk IS NULL
```

You're joining all this stuff together to get one row for each user / institution / exam / download log item.  Then you're using `l.exam_pk IS NULL` to pull out the not-yet-downloaded exams (the LEFT JOIN will fail and place a NULL in that column when there's no downloaded log entry).

If you need the result set for just one user, append `AND u.users_pk = something` to this query.

This isn't debugged. You'll probably get a bunch of 1064 errors as you fiddle around getting this to work. I don't think SO will be able to help you with those.

Comment: Great list of pro tips :)